# Diseño responsivo en formularios

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

tengo un formulario donde dos inputs están alineado, el problema que tengo es que no soy capaz de poner que cuando sea una versión móvil pegue el salto y se posicione debajo.

Seguramente sea un pego, pero para el diseño...

```html
              <form>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <!-- /btn-group -->
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="resultado" placeholder="IDENTIFICACIÓN">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="escaner">ESCANEAR</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>                       
                    </div>            
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="resultado2" placeholder="ORDER DE TRABAJO">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="escaner2">ESCANEAR</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>                       
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bien lo que debes entender este momento es como funciona el grid de `Bootstrap` nota que una fila esta compuesta de 12 columnas. Por lo tanto al decirle a los `div` con la clase `col-xs-6` estas diciendo que tomen 6 de las 12 columnas.

> Creo que xs no se usa mas, por lo tanto va de forma general en adelante

Ahora bien leyendo tu caso deberías tomar las 12 columnas con `col-12` y agregar las clases extras para cuando ya no estas en móvil. Es decir debes agregar algo parecido a esto `col-md-6` con esto esta diciendo que sí la pantalla es mayor a `768px` tome 6 de las 12 columnas.

Y tendrías algo como lo siguiente:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      columna de 12 en sm y de 6 en md
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      columna de 12 en sm y de 6 en md
    </div>
</div>
```

Nota que puedes seguir agregando mas clases para el resto de medidas `lg, xl, etc`.

[Grid de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: Efectivamente, la clase `col-xs-*` dejó de utilizarse a partir de la v4, aunque al parecer el OP utiliza la v3, podría usar igualmente `.col-xs-12`, en este caso `.col-md-*` se aplicaría a pantallas mayores que `992px`